# error: use of undeclared identifier 'llvm' when running CMake for OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, c++builder, rad-studio

Specifications:
Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3
CMake: 3.19.4
OpenCV: 4.7.0

When attempting to create the Borland MakeFiles using the RAD Studio Command Prompt and executing the following CMake command:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=bcc32x.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing" -G "Borland Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_WEBP=OFF -DWITH_OPENEXR=OFF -DWITH_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_TIFF=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_JASPER=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_PROTOBUF=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DBUILD_IPP=OFF -DWITH_IPP=OFF -DWITH_ADE=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF -DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON VERBOSE=1 -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH="C:\OpenCV\opencv_contrib-4.7.0\modules" C:/openCV/opencv-4.7.0
```

At approximately 5% into the 'make install' process, the following error occurs:

```
[ 5%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/algorithm.cpp.obj
Embarcadero C++ 7.40 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
C:\OpenCV\opencv-4.7.0\modules\core\src\algorithm.cpp:
In file included from C:\OpenCV\opencv-4.7.0\modules\core\src\algorithm.cpp:43:
In file included from C:\OpenCV\opencv-4.7.0\modules\core\src/precomp.hpp:88:
C:/OpenCV/opencv-4.7.0/modules/core/include\opencv2/core/hal/intrin.hpp:83:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'llvm'
return llvm.cttz.i32(value, true);
^
1 error generated.

** error 1 ** deleting modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\src\algorithm.cpp.obj

** error 1 ** deleting modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\all

** error 1 ** deleting all
```

Upon examining the file where the error occurs, it appears that the issue arises from using Clang for the Borland MakeFiles. Although one solution is to use CMake for LLVM to include the necessary headers, I'm unsure of an alternative method to resolve this error.